# How to make PhoneGap - Android set up process as one step build?

Tags: android, cordova, build

We started to develop mobile apps for our existing web application by using phonegap. Here we supposed to follow different steps to build the mobile app for different operating systems.
Now we started with Android, for that we need to follow some steps to set up the project to create app(Download ADT, copy required jars from phonegap sdk into adt eclipse lib folder, copy the xml file, and change the Manifest file)
So we do not want all the team follows the steps required to set up environment, Is there any way to reduce these steps or Can we make the whole process as a build?

1) May i know what files to checked-in and how to checked-in into Git?
2) How to check out the project?

It is really becoming pain to build the project, I do not know how the people sharing phonegap project code and how they are checking out the project.
Please help me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend to use the command line tool to build your project, so it can be used easily for all your members of your team.

**1) Commit the appropriate files in your source control**

- www folder (mandatory)
- config.xml (mandatory)
- hooks ( if used )
- merges ( if used )

The rest should be ommited from your source control as it will be generated each time you build your project.

**2) Each developer will have to add the platform he wants to build the app.**

```
 cordova platform add android
 cordova platform add ios
```

This step will create a platform(android, ios ...) in your platform folder with all the files needed for cordova to package it.

**3) Add the necessary plugins for your app (exemple below)**

```
cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.device
```

This will add the plugin in your plugin folder as well as updating automatically your AndroidManifest.xml located in your platform/android/AndroidManifest.xml. Usually, permissions in AndroidManifest.xml will be added automatically by the plugins. You should never update AndroidManifest.xml manually

By the way, I would recommend to implement a hook mechanism to add plugins automatically when adding a platform, so your members of your team won't have to do the step 3. [Here is the way to do it nicely](http://devgirl.org/2013/11/12/three-hooks-your-cordovaphonegap-project-needs/)

**EDIT: Since cordova 3.5.0, we can define plugins to be used in config.xml like below:**

```
<feature name="Network Information">
    <param name="id" value="org.apache.cordova.network-information" />
    <param name="version" value="0.2.10" />
</feature>
```

And restore them automatically with:

```
cordova restore plugins --experimental
```

As a matter of fact, we don't need to have hooks or add plugins manually 
END EDIT

**Build the project for Android**

```
cordova build android
```

This command is the shorthand for `cordova prepare android && cordova compile android`
This will package your project into a nice file ready to deploy in `platforms/android/ant-build/`

Comment: Thank you for your answer florent, could you please look at my another question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24955422/pushnotification-register-using-gcm-is-not-receiving-registration-id?noredirect=1#comment38791847_24955422.

Comment: hi @Florent, in the 1st step you said we will checked-in empty directory. May i know why we need it? I tried to check-in using git but it does not allow.

Comment: There is a problem if you use the hooks to add plugins automatically. For some reason, if plugins folder is not present, cordova plugin add xxx will fail. I have created a plugins folder with a .gitignore in it containing: * !.gitgnore

Comment: We are not using hooks for now.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need Eclipse to build Phonegap/Cordova, you can just call `cordova build android` on the command line. See the [Cordova Command-Line docs](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.5.0/guide_cli_index.md.html#The%20Command-Line%20Interface). The .apk ends up in `platforms/android/ant-build/`.

When you are ready to upload to Google Play you just need to zipalign and sign the .apk, simple steps explained in [Building and Running from the Command Line](http://developer.android.com/tools/building/building-cmdline.html) in the Android docs.

As for what to checkin, you don't need the platforms folder, that can just be regenerated. In principle you just need the code that you wrote, so only these:

- config.xml
- www folder
- merges folder (if you use it)
- cordova/plugins (or just re-add the plugins, static files in essence)

Comment: what about AndroidManifest.xml file, I think we need to add some user permissions to this file manually.

Comment: You can add those via config.xml as well, then AndroidManifest.xml will be re-generated based on those values.

Answer (score 1):

you can use yeoman phonegap project boilerplate, for example [this](https://github.com/dsimard/grunt-angular-phonegap)

Comment: Can you elaborate more about your answer. I visited the link you have provided but i did not get much idea about it.

Comment: looks like my link was deprecated with newer version, which I updated in my answer. Just follow the getting started section.

Comment: I can not use your plugin which is in alpha stage.

Answer (score 1):

Please use answer
[Versioning for different platforms with phonegap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21237101/versioning-for-different-platforms-with-phonegap/21544236)
 for information about Git configuration. You also should follow [Android Platform Guide](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.5.0/guide_platforms_android_index.md.html) to setup development environment across all machines for your developers.

Answer (score 0):

Jenkins is your friend. Although its main purpose is to provide CI but once the project is setup its a life saver when it comes to making releases.

so try out something like this 
 - setup jenkins server
 - connect git to jenkins
 - install phonegap plugins.
 - You can specify any additional pre or post build steps to your commandline

[Link to Jenkins](http://jenkins-ci.org/)